# Possibilities of refactoring classes which have same extends but invokes methods from each other

Tags: php, class, refactoring

There are classes A and B both extend class C and there are some common methods in class C that are needed for both class A and B.

There are cases that it needs to invoke the method in class B from class A, which is at the moment achieved by creating an object of class B in class A. But, more and more methods are added into class C, so it is inefficient to create an object of class B inside class A due to the duplication.

My question's that what are the possible solutions to refactoring the classes so that they have better structure, e.g using object oriented, factory pattern, etc.?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If there are cases where methods from class A need to be called in class B, isnt it better to move them to class C?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Traits](http://php.net/traits) (only PHP >= 5.4.0).

Answer (score 0):

If the methods needed by A and B can be factored out into a single responsibility then you might consider adding class D which is then used by class A and B.  The Single Responsibility Principal (SRP) is the S in SOLID, which are guidelines for object oriented design.

You can find plenty of information about SOLID in general, and the application of SRP in PHP on Google.  I gave a presentation to our local PHP Meetup Group on SRP which can be found online here: [SRP Presentation](http://blog.vicmetcalfe.com/2011/11/02/solid-php-code-smells-part-1-single-responsibility-principle/)